# How do I add a Auth0Provider to a NextJS project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, auth0

According to [the docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react#getting-started) I should be able to do something like this

```
// index.tsx

export default function Home() {
    let domain = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
    let clientId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
    return (
        <Auth0Provider domain={domain} clientId={clientId} authorizationParams={{
            redirect_uri: window.location.origin
        }}>
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>THEJackieGleason</title>
                    <meta name="description" content="My Personal Website"/>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
                    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
                </Head>
                <Header/>
                <div className={`${styles.wrapper} z-10`}>
                    <ThemeProvider theme={main}>
                        <HomePage/>
                        <Footer/>
                    </ThemeProvider>
                </div>

            </>
        </Auth0Provider>
    )
}
```

But when I try to build I get

error - Error [ReferenceError]: window is not defined
at Home (webpack-internal:///./pages/index.tsx:73:23)
at renderWithHooks (C:\Users\jacki\Code\next-site\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)

[image]

So how would I do this and still be able to access the window object?

Comment: the code is good, window is a global object representing the DOM and accessible from any component. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

IMO the problem is with the package, can you add the content of your `package.json` file?

Comment: Whole project should be available at https://github.com/jrgleason/next-site/tree/WORKING

Comment: of course window is not defined if page is server side rendered

Comment: @VladVladov that is why I mentioned the file name I am not a big nextjs guy so I am unsure what is rendered server side and what is rendered client side. My main problem is I use the index for my layout. Maybe I need to create a wrapper component?

Comment: NM creating a wrapper has the same problem I know setting works and I am pretty sure the variable will be there at some point just not right away so I am confused how to get it. For example this works fine https://github.com/jrgleason/next-site/blob/WORKING/components/Header.tsx#L60

Comment: if you are using nextjs then read https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/nextjs/interactive

Comment: @VladVladov That seems to be for handling serverside tokens I was looking for PKCE.

Comment: I say that because it talks about having to use the router for the redirect and stuff and I am just redirecting back to the original url. So that has more setup than I need for PKCE I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work using useEffect...

```
const [redirectUrl, setRedirectUrl] = useState<string>();
useEffect(() => {
    setRedirectUrl(window.location.origin);
    console.log(`Origin is ${redirectUrl}`);
}, []);
return redirectUrl && (
    <Auth0Provider domain={domain} clientId={clientId} authorizationParams={{
        redirect_uri: redirectUrl
    }}>
        <Header/>
        <div className={`${styles.wrapper} z-10`}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={main}>
                <HomePage/>
                <Footer/>
            </ThemeProvider>
        </div>
    </Auth0Provider>
)
```